# Supporting Delphi 7 apps in D2006 / D2009

Tags: delphi, legacy-code

I started occupational programming with Delphi when the Turbos came out , and have licenses for Delphi 2006 Turbo Pro and Delphi 2009 Professional. I have been asked to support another in-house tool, written by another occupational programmer, who has since retired. 
It's a Windows program, but it was developed with Delphi 6 using the CLX library rather than the VCL.

From what I gather, the CLX library was QT based and was removed prior to Delphi 2006.The support only consists of a few bug fixes and some minor tweaks, so I would rather not port the code to VCL, if i can avoid it.

Is it possible to install CLX support into either Delphi 2006 or 2009?

Comment: If you don't need the form designer you might be able to download FreeCLX and compile the app with a recent Delphi compiler - I have never tried this (or even read about it) however.

Comment: I'll look into FreeCLX- I was not aware of the project. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe not a direct answer but if you upgrade to Delphi XE, you will also get license keys for some of the older versions of Delphi down to 7, and Delphi 7 included CLX (it was dropped in Borland Delphi 2006).

Comment: Not a direct answer, but looks like the best option at the moment. I could probably wring some money out of the boss for this. Was this the case for Delphi 2009 or is it a new promotion?

Comment: No, it's only for Delphi XE and for limited time I think.

Comment: I think it is not for limited time... for what I read it looks you will get that "promotion" until the release of XE2.

Comment: But Upgrading pro is Eur 100 off here  (399 instead of 499) till end of september though. I assume everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is: no. Unfortunately I don't know any long answer which could tell you how to workaround this.

Answer (score 2):

If there isn't an easy way (and I suspect that there is not), you may need to continue using D7. D2009 is going to introduce the hassle of Unicode, and even going to D2006 is going to cause problems with 3rd-party libraries.
You could run both versions of Delphi on the same machine, but another option would be to use a VM for the legacy development. Either set up a new instance, or you could use the VMWare Converter to convert the other developer's entire machine into a VM image, which you could run on your machine, via the free VMWare Player.

BTW, VMWare Converter is a GREAT way to preserve old environments, to allow maintenance on older software that really needs to use a particular Delphi version, on a particular OS, "just like I left it".  If you have a bunch of dusty computers under your desk, consider this option.  VMWare Converter is the only tool I know of that will easily convert a physical machine to a useable VM that will run anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't add support for CLX to your other Delphi versions.

If it's in-house software, then your company should still have the in-house Delphi installation used to develop it. Multiple Delphi versions can co-exist on the same system; install earlier versions before installing later versions.

If the former employee took that installation with him when he left, can you get it back? I wouldn't expect it really belongs to him anyway. You said he retired; that wasn't a euphemism for *died*, was it? If not, then you can still contact him.

Comment: It was developed using his own private license, as a hobby programmer. Retired was a euphemism for going to live on a yacht somewhere in the Caribbean without a contact number. Living the dream, as they say ;)